# Umbraco 7 mvc existing database connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-connection, petapoco, umbraco7

I have a new project in umbraco 7 using mvc. I have installed umbraco to an existing database on sql server (nor sql server express).

I'm now trying petapoco database connection and inserts (http://creativewebspecialist.co.uk/2013/07/16/umbraco-petapoco-to-store-blog-comments/). I don't get any errors but the records in the database table is not inserted.

I am wondering if I have the database connection set up properly or the record is going somewhere else perhaps?

In my connection string says Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Umbraco.sdf;Flush Interval=1;

The database name is obviously different. Shall I use classic database connection string in this case?

Comment: do you connect to the DB or the record is not inserted?

Comment: @EduardoMolteni the record is not inserted in the database (1) I set up for umbraco. However my connection string in web.config leads to umbraco.sdf (2) instead to that database (1) so I'm thinking - is my script inserting the row in the wrong database? How to check the content of umbraco.sdf (2)? How to force umbraco to use the correct database (1) it was set up for? I hope my explanation makes sense. Thanks